# How to change MethodHandle arguments after being inserted?

Tags: java, methodhandle

Suppose you have `MethodHandle` and some arguments have been specified, how to change those arguments after being set?

```
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.*;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.*;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

public class SomeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MethodHandle methodHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(SomeTest.class,
                "someMethod", methodType(void.class, String.class));

        methodHandle = MethodHandles.insertArguments(methodHandle, 1, "Hi");

        // this invoke calls with "Hi", which is fine
        methodHandle.invoke(new SomeTest());

        // here, how to change the arguments to be e.g. "Hello" instead of "Hi"

        methodHandle.invoke(new SomeTest());

    }

    public void someMethod(String a) {
        System.out.println("Called with " + a);
    }
}
```

I have tried to use MethodHandles.[filterArguments()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#filterArguments-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-int-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle...-)

```
....
    methodHandle = MethodHandles.filterArguments(methodHandle, 1,
            MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(SomeTest.class, "returnSomething",
                    methodType(String.class)));

    methodHandle.invoke(new SomeTest());
}

public static String returnSomething() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

but I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: too many filters
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newIllegalArgumentException(MethodHandleStatics.java:139)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.filterArgumentsCheckArity(MethodHandles.java:2623)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.filterArguments(MethodHandles.java:2595)
    at test.test.SomeTest.main(SomeTest.java:22)
```

Comment: Method handles are immutable and *encapsulate* behavior. There is no way to change a bound value. If you want to bind different values, keep the original method handle which has that parameter.

Answer (score 3):

2 methods:

- Reuse your original method handle and bind it to another string:

  ```java
  MethodHandle methodHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(
           SomeTest.class,
           "someMethod",
           methodType(void.class, String.class)
  );
  MethodHandle hi    = MethodHandles.insertArguments(methodHandle, 1, "Hi");
  MethodHandle hello = MethodHandles.insertArguments(methodHandle, 1, "Hello");
  hi.invoke(new SomeTest()); // "Hi"
  hello.invoke(new SomeTest()); // "Hello"
  ```
- Bind the second argument to a getter of a class member, which you manipulate. You have to filter the arguments with an "exactInvoker" that will perform the getter to actually get the String value. See:

  ```java
  public class SomeTest {
    public static class StringHolder {
      public String toPrint;

      StringHolder(String toPrint) {
        this.toPrint = toPrint;
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
      MethodHandle toPrintGetter = MethodHandles.lookup().findGetter(
              StringHolder.class,
              "toPrint", 
              String.class);
      MethodHandle someMethod = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(
              SomeTest.class,
              "someMethod", 
              MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class)
      );

      StringHolder holder = new StringHolder("Hi");
      someMethod = MethodHandles.filterArguments(
              someMethod,
              1,
              MethodHandles.exactInvoker(MethodType.methodType(String.class))
      );
      MethodHandle stringPrinter = MethodHandles.insertArguments(
              someMethod,
              1, 
              toPrintGetter.bindTo(holder)
      );

      stringPrinter.invokeExact(new SomeTest()); // prints "Hi"
      holder.toPrint = "Hello";
      stringPrinter.invokeExact(new SomeTest()); // prints "Hello"
    }

    public void someMethod(String a) {
      System.out.println("Called with " + a);
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: target and filter types do not match: (SomeTest,String)void, (MethodHandle)String`

Comment: Yes, typo on my side, the index for filterArguments should have been 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer changes the the method handle before the first call. Please check my posted code, I need to change the methodHandle after argument has been set.